# How can I run c++ web program in Windows using xampp Apache server?

Tags: html, c++, apache, xampp, windows-10

I am trying to learn C++ web programming. But i am not getting how to run below program inside browser. Can anyone tell me what should I do?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //This line is sent back to the browser and specify the content type to be displayed on the browser screen.
    cout << "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n";
    cout << "<html>\n";
    cout << "<head>\n";
    cout << "<title>Hello World - First CGI Program</title>\n";
    cout << "</head>\n";
    cout << "<body>\n";
    cout << "<h2>Hello World... This is my first CGI program.</h2>\n";
    cout << "</body>\n";
    cout << "</html>\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've never seen anyone program web application code in C. Maybe you should consider trying Node.js, Python, Ruby, PHP. Those languages are better suited towards web dev.

Comment: Yes I agree but it is possible to do it with C and C++ also. Thank you.

Comment: you could just write to and html file through f stream, and then open that file programatically.

Answer (score 0):

I searched about this question and then found the solution. So I thought let's answer my own question so that if someone stuck at this point in future then he/she may find it useful.
You need to do two main steps as below:-

**A] Configure apache server to successfully run cgi file:**

1. Download and install xampp on your system.
2. Open xampp and click on config button in apache line and then click on httpd.conf.
3. This will open httpd.conf file in notepad. Now make below changes in this file.

   - First find DocumentRoot using ctrl+f and change the line
     **DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs" to DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/cgi-bin"**
   - Now find **<Directory "C:/xampp/cgi-bin">** and modify as below in that:

```
  
    
        AllowOverride All
        #Options None
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        Require all granted
```

- Save this changes then close the file and after that start apache server.

**B] Produce .cgi file to run in browser:**

1. Write your c++ program. You can refer my program to understand how to write html code using C++.
2. Compile your program.

   - For this open command prompt and go to the file path
   - Now run this command: **g++ fileName.cpp -o fileName.cgi**
   - This command compile code and produce output file with extension **.cgi**
   - You can give different name to .cgi file than your .cpp file.
3. Now check whether it is successfully compiled or not. For this run below command:
   **fileName.cgi**. After hitting enter you will see only html code extracted from your c++ program in your command prompt.
4. Now put copy of this **.cgi** file in **cgi-bin** folder which is located at **C:/xampp/cgi-bin**.
   **Note:** If you put your source code in cgi-bin folder then you need not to do step 4.
5. Now open the browser and go to localhost. In my case **apache** server listens to port **8012** and my file name is **web1.cgi** so I entered this address to run my html code: **localhost:8012/web1.cgi**
6. After hitting enter you will get the desired output. Thank You.

Comment: Hello. It's not stated that a C++ compiler is needed, I tried opening the command prompt from XAMPP "shell" button, and type "g++" (Enter) - it says "'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command"